# Dart: Replace every letter in a string with an asterix using regxp

Tags: dart

I was trying to replace every letter in a string with an asterix using Dart and am having some difficulty. In Javascript it is:

```
'test'.replace(/./g, '*');
```

So in Dart, I tried the following:

```
'test'.replaceAll(new RegExp(r'/.'), '*');
'test'.replaceAll(new RegExp(r'\/.'), '*');
'test'.replaceAll(new RegExp(r'/./'), '*');
'test'.replaceAll(new RegExp(r'\/.\/'), '*');
```

I obviously don't quite understand how this should work as cannot seem to make this work.

Can anyone advise the correct way to do this with a short explanation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```dart
var regex = RegExp(r'[a-zA-Z]');
var replaced = 'some string / with \$ other = chars'.replaceAll(regex, '*');
```

[**DartPad example**](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/6d34431e78ea61a7e52b8d8259564591)

Comment: Hm, it doesn't quite solve it for me. I need to be sure it works for any character - so based on your example I am tryinging something like this now:
new RegExp(r'[a-zA-Z?=.*[!@#$%^&*£()"'+-_0-9]')
But is there no way to just say "cover everything"?

Comment: What exactly is "any character"? In your question you wrote "every letter". Are there any characters like line break or whatever that you don't want to match?

Comment: Try `new RegExp('.')`. As long as I don't know exactly what output you expect for what input, I can only guess though.

Comment: That works perfect. Thanks - sorry question not phrase too well!

Comment: Glad to hear :)

Answer (score 0):

without using regex I got a solution

```
Text('*' * subText.length)
```

Answer (score -1):

To anyone who needs to remove Special characters and other letters in a given string. Use the format below.

```
  String str = "a12.334tyz.78x";
  
  var newStr = str.replaceAll(new RegExp(r'[a-zA-Z.]'), ''); 
  print(newStr);
```

result
`1233478`

***Dart Pad***
https://dartpad.dev/